# Biblatex square brackets color

Tags: biblatex, color, brackets

How can I change the square brackets color of references in text using biblatex (numeric style)?

I know it can be done with natbib, but not using this package anymore.

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,spanish]{book}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{CeruleanRef}{RGB}{12,127,172}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,citecolor=CeruleanRef,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\bibpunct{\color{CeruleanRef}[}{\color{CeruleanRef}]}{,}{n}{}{;}

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\mainmatter

A reference: \cite{RBoehler1996}

\appendix

\backmatter

\bibliography{articles,reports,books,reviews}

\end{document}
```

With natbib I get this:
[image]

I want the same with biblatex and biber.

Comment: You mean the square brackets around the entries in the bibliography? Or those in the text? Or both? In answering this question, please provide us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that we can use. Helping us really does help you.

Comment: Quickly searching through the `natbib` documentation, I didn't find "color" there, so I don't know what kind of functionality that is.

(Something related and common is to color the reference with hyperref since it's a link, with `\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}`, but in "[1]" that will color only "1", and not the brackets.)

Comment: Do you want the brackets to also be hyperlinked?

Comment: @pst with the \bibpunct command

Comment: Please add a MWE of the fix you used before (and maybe of what you get with `natbib`).

Comment: If you used to use `\bibpunct` and have no intention to have hyperlinking, you can go with `\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bibleftbracket}{\blx@postpunct\textcolor{red}{[}}
\renewcommand*{\bibrightbracket}{\blx@postpunct\textcolor{red}{]}\midsentence}
\makeatother`. (Probably this will colour more more things red, if you do not want that we will need a more sophisticated answer.)

Comment: OK, so what happens here, is that `natbib` links the citation number (that's why it is turned turquoise-ish) and you colour the brackets to pretend they are linked as well, although they are not. You can get the "pretend look" by using the code in my comment above. But note that this really is not a thing you should be doing. `hyperref` colours links so we know they're there and you make your reader think there is a link even though there is none.

Comment: @moewe Excellent!

Comment: @Werner, I'd like to do your 1st option, I mean, change `[XX]` in the bibliography. Is it possible with `biber`? I know editing `bbl` but not too robust since `biber` changes it.

Comment: @Sigur: Consider [this example](https://pastebin.com/raw/1wiPRg04) which delays `\formatentry`'s definition to the first call to `\printbibliography`. At that time, you can change the colour - [example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BVVO.png).

Comment: @Werner, thanks. Nice! Also, moewe told me about `\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalphawidth}{\textcolor{red}{\bibleftbracket#1\bibrightbracket}}`. My problem now is to change the color of some items, not all. For example, only items from specific `.bib`.

Comment: @Sigur: Ask the question here on the site... with an appropriate minimal example, if course.

Comment: @Werner, it was solved with discussion [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417005/14757). Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you see there is that `hyperref` colours (cite) links (because you told it so in `colorlinks=true, citecolor=CeruleanRef`). Normally, when you cite only a certain part of that citation is actually turned into a link, with the numeric style only the number itself, not the brackets are linked. Your `natbib` fix did not extend the link to the brackets, it just coloured them in.

We can emulate that behaviour by adding `\color{CeruleanRef}` to the wrapper of the `\cite` command (I took it from `numeric.cbx`, if you use `numeric-comp.cbx` or another style, copy the definition of `\cite` from there)

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\color{CeruleanRef}\mkbibbrackets]% <--- this is new
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

for `numeric-comp`

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\color{CeruleanRef}\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Remember: This will not actually create a hyperlink, the text will just look like one. Hyperlinks with ranges that big can only be created in very special cases with a huge amount of work. (With `numeric-comp`, linking the brackets would not even make sense: Where is the link from the bracket supposed to link to.)

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{CeruleanRef}{RGB}{12,127,172}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=CeruleanRef]{hyperref}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\color{CeruleanRef}\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}
  \cite{companion,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c} and \cite{baez/article} \cite{aksin}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

One could also use a kludge as suggested in my comment

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bibleftbracket}{\blx@postpunct\textcolor{red}{[}}
\renewcommand*{\bibrightbracket}{\blx@postpunct\textcolor{red}{]}\midsentence}
\makeatother
```

This does have side-effects though: All opening brackets will be coloured red.

Comment: the idea of having colored brackets is not just for linking, but for reading a printed document (aesthetic reasons).