# Bibliography: Citations with [] but bibliography without []

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

I need to create a document following these instructions for the bibliography:

[image: refs]

But I haven't been able to find a way to use brackets in the citations but no brackets in the bibliography. Can some point me to a way of doing this with bibtex or biblatex?

Comment: Has a particular bibliography style been suggested to you?

Comment: @Mico That was all the bibliography info given to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `biblatex` that is as easy as using a `numeric`-like style and issuing

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}
```

Then

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson} then \cite{worman,geer}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

gives

[image: citations and bibliography of example]

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the end of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/174141/80130), you could put the following directly before your `\printbibliography` (**not** in the document header):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\bibleftbracket}{\blx@postpunct}
\renewcommand*{\bibrightbracket}{\blx@postpunct.\midsentence}
\makeatother
```

It works at least in my document with LuaLaTeX and biber, but should also work with biblatex.

Comment: I cannot recommend that approach. Even if you put this just before the `\printbibliography` you will still mess up all square brackets set by `biblatex`. (Also note that this solution works for the package `biblatex` regardless of the TeX (Lua/Xe/LaTeX) engine and the backend used (BibTeX/Biber))