# biblatex color each element of a bib in a different color

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, color

I am using biblatex (with xelatex). To be more specific I use Zotero and then I export from Zotero to the bib format.

Everything works fine but my bibliography is only in black color. That is the normal behaviour of course... However, my aim is to color each bib element differently for testing purposes in order to make sure I did not forget an element of the bib such as 'volume'. For instance I would like to apply the following color code.

```
    volume -> dark blue
    pages -> turqoise
    url -> brown
    title -> red
    isbn -> yellow
    booktitle -> pink
    publisher -> orange
    author -> grey
    date -> black
```

Is it possible to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the way a field is displayed with `\DeclareFieldFormat`.

So all you have to do is redefine `\DeclareFieldFormat` for the relevant fields.

There are a few caveats, though,

1. Not all 'fields' are *fields*. `biblatex` knows fields, lists and name lists. These three types use different `\Declare...Format` directives. So you need to know the type of your field
2. You need to know the original definition if you don't want to override it completely. I'm assuming here that you still want italics and quotation marks as usual, only the colour should change.

   - Even though it is possible to patch the field format with `xpatch`'s `\xpretofieldformat`, you need to know if any types get a special treatment. Because you can only patch the general or the type-specific format, but never both at the same time.

For the standard styles most formatting directives can be found in `biblatex.def`.

For fields this should be as easy as searching for the field, copying the `\DeclareFieldFormat` and adding in a `\color{...}` command in the definition. Don't forget that there might be several type-sepcific `\DeclareFieldFormat`s for the same field (in the standard styles you should find them next to each other).

For lists you would do a similar thing, but you would search for `\DeclareListFormat`. (See `publisher` below.)

Names are more complicated. You first have to find out which name format the name you want to colour uses. `author` uses the format `sortname` in `style=authoryear`. And `sortname` is defined as `family-given/given-family`. So we copy the definition of `family-given/given-family`, call it `coloured:family-given/given-family`, add `\colour{...}` and tell `sortname` to be `coloured:family-given/given-family` from now on.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\DeclareFieldFormat{volume}{\color{DarkBlue}\bibstring{volume}~#1}% volume of a book
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\color{DarkBlue}#1}% volume of a journal

\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{\color{Turquoise}\mkpageprefix[bookpagination]{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{url}{\mkbibacro{URL}\addcolon\space\color{Brown}\url{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\color{Red}\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]
  {title}{\color{Red}\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat
  [suppbook,suppcollection,suppperiodical]
  {title}{\color{Red}#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{isbn}{\mkbibacro{ISBN}\addcolon\space \color{Yellow}#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{\color{Pink}\mkbibemph{#1}}

\DeclareListFormat{publisher}{%
  \color{Orange}%
  \usebibmacro{list:delim}{#1}%
  #1\isdot
  \usebibmacro{list:andothers}}

\DeclareNameFormat{coloured:family-given/given-family}{%
  \color{Grey}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
    {\ifgiveninits
       {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiven}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}%
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid\namepartgiven}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid\namepartprefix}}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{name:revsdelim}}}
    {\ifgiveninits
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}
       {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiven}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{coloured:family-given/given-family}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,vizedom:related,westfahl:space,worman,geer,nussbaum,ctan}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use the Biber option `--validate-datamodel` when compiling to help you check if your entries conform to the data model.

Comment: Hello moewe thanks so much for the answer. This is exactely what I was looking for. It works like a charm :)

Comment: Do you know how to change the color of some item label, incuding brackets? I mean, for example, how to make red the `[DK]` in the bibliography entry `[DK] Donald ...`. I'm using `biber`.

Comment: @Sigur In the bibliography that would usually be the field format `labelnumberwidth` (for `numeric` styles) or `labelalphawidth` (for `alphabetic` styles). If that does not work, please ask a new question with an MWE that shows which style you use.

Comment: @moewe, many thanks. So, with `\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalphawidth}{\textcolor{red}{\bibleftbracket#1\bibrightbracket}}` I got all labels in red. Now, I'd like to do this for some, not all of them. Regards.

Comment: @Sigur How do you want to tell `biblatex` which labels to turn red? You could use `\ifkeyword`, `\ifentrytype` or similar tests. If that does not give you what you want, please ask a new question with detailed specification of what you are after and an MWE.

Comment: @moewe I have two `bib` files, and citations from one should be printed in red. So, you say to insert some keyword on those bib items? Then, I embrace the filed format command?

Comment: @Sigur You could automate adding a keyword based on the `.bib` file (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35279/35864) and then you would say `\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalphawidth}{%
  \ifkeyword{fileone}
    {\textcolor{red}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}
    {\ifkeyword{filetwo}
       {\textcolor{red}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}
       {\mkbibbrackets{#1}}}}` or something like that.

Comment: @moewe, thanks so much. You helped a lot. Let me try then. Regards.